# Coq - Universal quantifiers in hypoteses

Tags: predicate, universal, coq, quantifiers

I would like to prove the following theorem

```
Goal (forall x, P x \/ Q x) -> (forall x, P x) \/ (forall x, Q x).
```

with context

```
1 subgoal
P : nat -> Prop
Q : nat -> Prop
R : nat -> nat -> Prop
H : forall x : nat, P x \/ Q x
______________________________________(1/1)
(forall x : nat, P x) \/ (forall x : nat, Q x)
```

The statement seems to be correct in predicate logic, but I have no idea of how to prove it. The problem is essentially that I cannot eliminate all the forall at once, but I cannot neither apply left or right before destructing the hypotesis H.

Is there a straightforward way for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take `P` to be evenness, `Q` to be oddity, and you should see that your theorem is flawed.